# Best way to setup interactive line charts in React?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm looking to create a line chart graphing some data in a React app. It seems like a ton of libraries, d3 and many wrapping it, can handle this. However, the special functionality I need is that clicking (and ideally click + drag) on the chart should plot an additional horizontal line at the y-coordinate the viewer clicks. As they click and drag the line, it should move.

It seems that a number of the charting libraries built on top of D3 for react (NVD3, for example) don't easily support callbacks for clicks on the chart background. It was suggested in the VictoryJS chat to create a custom container to help with this feature.

What are some of the best approaches to accomplish this in a React app?

**Edit** Adding a JSFiddle to show my experimentation: https://jsfiddle.net/asardana/nuj5t9ks/

```
const { VictoryChart, VictoryLine } = Victory;

class LineWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  click(e) {
    const minY = 58;//from observation, this is the minmum clientY value I receive on clicks (not sure why)

    //pad threshold with SVG rect offset
    const YThreshold = (e.clientY - minY + 50);
    this.setState({
        YThreshold: YThreshold
    });

    //logging below to try to figure out what Y values
    //I have access to.
    //Can't seem to find anything that will let me determine relative Y click on the svg <rect> itself, 
    //which is why I'm calculating it above
    console.log('YThres:', YThreshold);
        console.log(e.clientY);
    console.log(e.pageY);
    console.log(e.screenY);
    console.log(e.nativeEvent);
    }
  render() {
    const svgRectX = 50, svgRectY = 50;
    const svgRectH = 50, svgRectW = 150;
    return (
      <g height={this.props.height} width={this.props.width} >

        {/*place a rectangle overlay to capture clicks for the threshold line*/}
        <rect x={svgRectX} y={svgRectY} width={svgRectW} height={svgRectH} 
         onClick={this.click.bind(this)} opacity="0.1"/>

        {/*Once a click happens on the rect, a YThreshold will be set to draw the threshold line*/} 
        {this.state.YThreshold && <line x1={svgRectX} y1={this.state.YThreshold} x2={svgRectX + svgRectW}y2={this.state.YThreshold}
              stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>}
      { this.props.children }
      </g>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <VictoryChart height={150} width={250}>
    <LineWrapper height={150} width={250}>
      <VictoryLine height={150} width={250} 
            x={"x"}
            y={"y"}
            data={[
            {x: 0, y: .1},
            {x: 2, y: .9},
            {x: 3, y: .4},
            {x: 4, y: .5}
          ]}/>
        </LineWrapper>
  </VictoryChart>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I've wrapped the VictoryLine in a custom container that has a  overlay, on which I listen for clicks. There are multiple problems with this approach: 1) I have to determine how much of the VictoryChart's overall dimensions the rect inside the axis will take up and offset it down to the correct position. 2) I can plot the threshold line based on raw coordinate information, which also comes in with weird offsets, so I'm doing ugly math to figure out the actual location. 3) I have to translate the threshold line to the chart's actual Y value that it corresponds to.

There must be a much better way that this - I'm just not seeing it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: @alstonp thanks for the response - edited the original with some info. I also tried including an <NVD3Chart> and adding some click handlers to that, but the handlers weren't called and I wasn't sure why.